# Black Spots On My Mesh in Unreal, but not Blender

Tags: light, shadows, unreal-engine

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I'm trying to create a model to import into Unreal. I've noticed an issue where there are black spots that appear in Unreal that I can't find in Blender. I've made multiple attempts to visualize/fix this in Blender, (Triangulate Modifier, Rendered Mode in both Eevee and Cycles), but nothing has worked. I've searched Blender and Unreal forums but couldn't find anything useful.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

I should note I can only cause this to happen when using the "Time of Day" level preset in Unreal, or the Ultra Dynamic Sky plugin. Regular Unreal lighting doesn't appear to have any issues, but I believe this is due to how little lighting there is.

I'm hoping there is a way to fix this in Blender. I don't know if there is. Maybe something to do with lightmaps? I don't really know how that works, and any tutorials on Youtube about it are either outdated or not really informative (that I've found, anyways). Would greatly appreciate any help.

Also, since I can't replicate the issue in Blender, I'm working blind. I would be grateful for any information about how to replicate the issue in Blender.

I do realize this might not be an issue with me or Blender, but an Unreal issue. However, I feel it's mostly likely me that's the problem since I'm new to Blender.

In case this helps, my Blender version is 2.92, and my Unreal version is 4.26.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

So after 8 days of trial and error, I figured it out. It was an Unreal issue, which could be solved in a couple different ways, depending on what you are willing to allow. Figured I should post here to help out anyone else who might have the same issue later on.

### Option #1: Use a Skeletal Mesh instead of Static Mesh

For some unknown reason, the issue does not appear if you import the object as a "Skeletal Mesh" instead of a "Static Mesh".

After doing research into the differences between the two (use skeletal if you have animations, static if you don't, essentially), I have come to the conclusion that this will work for me, as I need my object to have some animations. That being said, I still needed a Static Mesh version of a similar object, and that's what Option 2 is for.

### Option #2: Two-Sided Distance Field Generation

If you need to keep it a static mesh, then you will need to ensure you have this setting checked on the static mesh. This can be found by double-clicking the static mesh in your content browser, and under the Details panel, navigating to LOD 0 > Build Settings > Two-Sided Distance Field Generation. That simple.

Hope this helps anyone else out there!

Comment: So this is actually no Blender related issue?